# javascript POST 404 request not found

Tags: javascript, python, post

I am trying to mimic a simple post request with these parameters:

[image]

I am using python to create the post request

```
    s.post("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/169754/add", params=payload)
```

These are the parameters I am using right now

```
    payload = {"utf8": "%E2%9C%93", "authenticity_token": "PeeJppo%2BA5PQHs0bgA7Z%2B7%2BVkSka1N5DRBEpXRFw45w%3D", "size": "32741", "commit": "add+to+cart"}
```

Whenever I run the script. I get a 404 Page not found error. Where am I going wrong?

This is the page of the product I am trying to add to cart:

http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/clrwu0gsz/white

Comment: If you check the url in a navigator, it responds indeed with a 404 error. The page might have been moved or deleted, or maybe it doesn't support post request.

Comment: @kerwan I see that. but i'm trying to emulate how the website linked above "added" the product to cart. how would i go about doing that

Comment: Maybe the website doesn't allow outside sources to perform this action. Possibly to do with bots being against their rules...

Comment: I think millerbr is right, the "authenticity_token" makes me think that you might have to give a valid token to the request in order to do what you want.

Comment: an identical script was made using a recycled authenticity token, and it worked for months until a recent release. bots still currently exist trying to achieve the same concept.